# How can I make my filter work as an "and" instead of "or" when there are multiple values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, angular-reactive-forms

I have a working filter with two limitations.

1: It works as an 'or' instead of an 'and' when there are multiple values.

e.g.

```
filterArr = {'claim_number': null, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John Connor', 'service_date': null}

this.rows = [ 
   { 'claim_number': 1234, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John Connor', 'service_date': '1/10/2018', etc ...}
   { 'claim_number': 4567, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'James Brown', 'service_date': '3/11/2018', etc ...}
   { 'claim_number': 7890, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'Steven Hawkins', 'service_date': '2/1/2018', etc ...}
```

Currently all of these items would match when only the first one should because only the first one has both "status: Approved" and "patient: John Connor."

2: The second limitation is I want to trigger a match when there is a partial string that matches a full string in this.rows.

e.g.

```
filterArr = {'claim_number': 12, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': null, 'service_date': null}

this.rows = [ 
    { 'claim_number': 1234, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John 
       Connor', 'service_date': '1/10/2018', etc ...}
    { 'claim_number': 4567, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'James 
       Brown', 'service_date': '3/11/2018', etc ...}
    { 'claim_number': 7890, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'Steven Hawkins', 'service_date': '2/1/2018', etc ...}
```

Again only number one should match as it contains the correct "status" and the first two digits in "claim_number."

This should be relatively simple as I had it working when I was passing a specific key, but now that the filter is dynamic it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I've attached a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/London804/rpL9tcye/1/) for reference though it's not executing correctly because I'm using Reactive Forms in an Angular project.  Also, please only include answers that are solved using ES5 or ES6. I can't use flatMap() and other experimental features. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I ultimately ended up using. I found it to be the most straightforward.

```
@Input() filters: Array<any>;
allRows: Array<any> = [];

applyFilters() {
    this.rows = this.allRows;

    this.rows = this.rows.filter(row => {
        for (let filter of this.filters) {
            const filterVal = this.filtersForm.get(filter.key).value;
            const rowVal = row[filter.key];

            if (!!filterVal && rowVal.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterVal.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this would work for you:

```js
const rows = [ { 'claim_number': '1234', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John Connor', 'service_date': '1/10/2018'}, { 'claim_number': '4567', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'James Brown', 'service_date': '3/11/2018'}, { 'claim_number': '7890', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'Steven Hawkins', 'service_date': '2/1/2018'} ]

const filtrate = (i, f) => {
  const vals = Object.values(f).reduce((r,c) => (!!c ? r.push(c) : 0, r), [])
  return vals.every(x => Object.values(i).some(y => y.includes(x)))
}
const filterBy = (arr, f) => arr.filter(x => filtrate(x, f))

console.log(filterBy(rows, {'claim_number': null, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John Connor', 'service_date': null}))
console.log(filterBy(rows, {'claim_number': '12', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': null, 'service_date': null}))
```

The idea is to first `clean/sanitize` the filter object and once you have only clean values then actually do the whole searching via `Array.every` & `Array.some` & `Array.includes`.

Also note that I converted the numbers to strings since it seems that is your intent if you are going to search if `12` is part of `1234` etc.

Here is the same code expanded for clarity:

```js
const rows = [ { 'claim_number': '1234', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John Connor', 'service_date': '1/10/2018'}, { 'claim_number': '4567', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'James Brown', 'service_date': '3/11/2018'}, { 'claim_number': '7890', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'Steven Hawkins', 'service_date': '2/1/2018'} ]

const filtrate = (item, filter) => {
  const values = Object.values(filter).reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if(!!current)
    accumulator.push(current) 
    return accumulator
  }, [])
  return values.every(value => {
    return Object.values(item).some(itm => itm.includes(value))
  })
}
const filterBy = (allRows, filterObject) => {
  return allRows.filter(row => filtrate(row, filterObject))
}

console.log(filterBy(rows, {'claim_number': null, 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': 'John Connor', 'service_date': null}))
console.log(filterBy(rows, {'claim_number': '12', 'status': 'Approved', 'patient': null, 'service_date': null}))
```

Comment: Akrion, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't appear to work in my code. I'm not sure how to apply this your answer is a little terse, particularly 'const filtrate.' I don't understand what r and c are?

Comment: I added an expanded version. Let me know if that one is clearer and works for you.